# compileDebugJavaWithJava' task (current target is 11) and compileDebugKotlin task (current target is 17) jvm target compatibility should be same Java

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

I just updated my `react-native` project to 0.72 and i am facing issue with my `TurboModule`. I did add

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

   kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '17'
    }
```

in my project's `build.gradle` as well as in turbomodule's `build.gradle` file.

I also changed `build.gradle.kts`

```
java {
  sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
  targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
  kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17.majorVersion
    apiVersion = "1.5"
    languageVersion = "1.5"
  }
}
```

Updated the same in android studio as well

[image]

Entire source code [here](https://github.com/CodingWithNobody/ReactNativeDummy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change java version from 17 to 11 it will work
change in your app.gradle java version like this

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
```

and download Javajdk 11 version like this [image: like this picture]

Comment: I have already done this. Please check my question again

Comment: @change your java version from 17 to 11

Comment: Update your answer and I will accept it

Comment: @BraveEvidence I updated answer please accept and I am happy that you fixed your problem

Comment: change jvmTarget to 11 as well